# Memoryleak with TBgraBitmap an ZXING in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, zxing, lazarus

I have a memory problem with TBgraBitmap in combination with the barcode detection ZXING in Lazarus. Does anyone see my problem?
After resize the image for a better detection, the memory grows and grows.

It works, but it crashes because of running as a 32-bit assembly. I work with ca. 10 source tifs in color scanned mode and 300 dpi.

```
unit frmmain;

{$IFDEF FPC}
//{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
  {$mode delphi}{$H+}
{$ENDIF}

interface

uses
  {$ifdef FPC}
  LResources,
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef MSWindows}Windows, {$endif}
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, ComCtrls,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Clipbrd, Buttons, fpimage,
  Generics.Collections,
  ZXing.ReadResult,
  ZXing.BarCodeFormat,
  ZXing.DecodeHintType,
  ZXing.ResultPoint,
  ZXing.Scanmanager,
  UConvert, dateutils,
  {zum Vergrößern }BgraBitmap, BGRABitmapTypes,
  {für enum namen}typinfo;

type

  { TMainForm }

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    ListBoxFiles: TListBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBoxFilesClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function GetAppPath(): string;
    function GetFiles(LPfad: string): TStringList;
    function Resample(Src: string; percent: integer): TBitmap;
  public
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  maxZoom: integer;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}



{ TMainForm }

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  scanner: TScanmanager;
  readResult: TReadResult;
  barcodeInt, zoom: integer;
  // pic: TPicture;
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  ListBoxFiles.Enabled := False;
  application.ProcessMessages;
  zoom := 100;
  while zoom <= 180 do
  begin
    //erkennen
    bmp := Resample(Label2.Caption, zoom);
    scanner := TScanmanager.Create(TBarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, nil); //TBarcodeFormat.auto
    readResult := scanner.Scan(bmp);

    //free mem
    FreeAndNil(bmp);
    //free mem
    FreeAndNil(scanner);

    application.ProcessMessages;
    if readResult <> nil then
    begin
      barcodeInt := Ord(readResult.BarcodeFormat);
      {barcodeTypeStr := TypInfo.GetEnumName(
        System.TypeInfo(ZXing.BarCodeFormat.TBarcodeFormat), barcodeInt);
      }
      Text := 'Zoom: ' + IntToStr(zoom) + ' : ' + readResult.Text +
        '   Code: ' + IntToStr(barcodeInt);
      if zoom > maxZoom then
        maxZoom := zoom;
      break;
    end
    else
      Text := 'Zoom: ' + IntToStr(zoom) + '-';
    zoom := zoom + 10;
    application.ProcessMessages;
    //free mem
    FreeAndNil(readResult);
  end;
  //show result
  Label1.Caption := 'Max. Zoom: ' + IntToStr(maxzoom);
  Button1.Enabled := True;
  ListBoxFiles.Enabled := True;
end;

function TMainForm.Resample(Src: string; percent: integer): TBitmap;
var
  Width, Height: integer;
  reSampleBitmap: TBgraBitmap;
  pic: TPicture;
begin
  //if percent = 100 then
  //begin
  //  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  //  Result.Assign(Src);
  //  exit;
  //end;
  //  reSampleBitmap := TBgraBitmap.Create();
  //  reSampleBitmap.LoadFromFile(Src);
  pic := TPicture.Create;
  pic.LoadFromFile(src);
  reSampleBitmap := TBgraBitmap.Create(pic.Bitmap);
  Width := round(reSampleBitmap.Height * percent / 100);
  Height := round(reSampleBitmap.Height * percent / 100);
  reSampleBitmap.ResampleFilter := rfBestQuality;
  reSampleBitmap := reSampleBitmap.Resample(Width, Height);// as TBGRABitmap;
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Assign(reSampleBitmap);
  FreeAndNil(reSampleBitmap);
  FreeAndNil(pic);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  maxZoom := 0;
  for i := 0 to ListBoxFiles.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ListBoxFiles.ClearSelection;
    ListBoxFiles.Selected[i] := True;
    ListBoxFilesClick(self);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ListBoxFilesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fullFilename: string;
  obj: TObject;
  bmp: TPicture;
begin
  obj := ListBoxFiles.Items.Objects[ListBoxFiles.ItemIndex];
  if obj <> nil then
  begin
    fullfilename := string(obj);
    Label2.Caption := fullfilename;
    bmp := TPicture.Create;
    bmp.LoadFromFile(fullfilename);
    Image1.Picture.Assign(bmp);
    FreeAndNil(bmp);
    obj := nil;
    Button1Click(self);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  sourceFolder, fileName: string;
  files: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  ListBoxFiles.Clear;
  Label2.Caption := '';
  maxZoom := 100;
  sourceFolder := GetAppPath() + 'Tifs\';
  //D:\EigeneDateien\Lazarus\ZXing\Tifs
  files := Getfiles(sourcefolder);
  for i := 0 to files.Count - 1 do
  begin
    fileName := ExtractFileName(files[i]);
    ListBoxFiles.AddItem(fileName, TObject(files[i]));
  end;
end;

function TMainForm.GetFiles(LPfad: string): TStringList;
var
  LSearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  if FindFirst(LPfad + '*.*', faAnyFile, LSearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if LSearchRec.Attr and faDirectory = 0 then
      begin
        Result.Add(LPfad + LSearchRec.Name);
      end;
    until FindNext(LSearchRec) <> 0;
    FindClose(LSearchRec);
  end;
end;


function TMainForm.GetAppPath(): string;
var
  appDir: string;
begin
  appDir := ExpandFileName(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName));
  appDir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(appDir);
  Result := appDir;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This line is the problematic (code is quite long, so there may be other issues)  `reSampleBitmap := reSampleBitmap.Resample(Width, Height);` You are assigning new bitmap to existing one and that will cause the leak because you no longer have reference to original bitmap and you cannot free it. You need to create another bitmap to store resampled image.

Comment: I suggest you to read [mcve] because you have included a lot of unnecessary code in your question.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue! Normally I'm a c# coder, and there this is okay. But of course not in pascal. Thanks a lot!